# Is there a tool for finding or visualizing bibliographic trails between two sources?

Tags: bibliometrics

As the questions indicates, I am curious if there is a tool that finds bibliographic trails ("cited by Y", "cites X") connecting two sources. I have found connectedpapers.com but this only works for inserting a single source.

Comment: Ask your local research librarians.

Comment: I don't know if one exists, but it could be made using the Scopus API: https://dev.elsevier.com/